# Dartlang: How to convert int from network to host order (and vice versa)

Tags: dart, flutter

How to convert int from network to host order (and vice versa).
In cpp it would be the ntohl and htonl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ByteData`, which is a ...

> sequence of bytes that also provides random and unaligned access to
>   the fixed-width integers and floating point numbers represented by
>   those bytes

For example:

```
  ByteData byteData = ByteData(4);
  byteData.setUint32(0, netValue, Endian.big);
  int hostValue = byteData.getUint32(0);
```

Chances are you'll actually want to use the underlying bytes - maybe to send in some network message. You could extract a `int` from a byte array like this:

```
  Uint8List bytes = Uint8List(4); // 4 byte list
  // read the network order int in bytes [0-3].
  int value = bytes.buffer.asByteData().getUint32(0, Endian.big);
```